# How to compile fIcy for BSD?

Tags: freebsd, compiling, make, bsd, netbsd

I'm trying to compile fIcy (https://gitlab.com/wavexx/fIcy) for NetBSD/FreeBSD.

When I'm executing the make command nothing happens. Even no error message.

The same source package compiles without problems with Debian 10.

Is the Makefile even compatible with BSD?

https://gitlab.com/wavexx/fIcy/blob/master/Makefile

The commands I used so far on FreeBSD 12:

```
pkg install gcc
wget https://gitlab.com/wavexx/fIcy/-/archive/master/fIcy-master.tar.gz
tar xfvz fIcy-master.tar.gz
cd fIcy-master
make

type make
make is /usr/bin/make
```

Comment: Could you add more details about your issue? Especially what commands you typed and the standard output of them. BTW, the makefile does not seem to be incompatible with your system and just ask for `gcc` and `make` programs (without mentioning the version, but since the tool is written in C++03, I am guessing that the version should not be a problem).

Comment: Please, do not add screenshots of terminals, but, instead, copy and paste what you typed and the standard output of each command typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use GNU's make as [README.rst](https://gitlab.com/wavexx/fIcy/blob/master/README.rst) says:

```
pkg install gmake
```

If you've already installed any other dependencies you should run

```
gmake all
```

(Note `g` is the first letter.)

Works for me but if you've any error message please post/edit it.

/Note: the GNU make and FreeBSD make aren't compatible. They can work as [POSIX make](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html) but have different extensions./

Comment: gmake worked fine.

Comment: I'm glad it works :)

Comment: @Lagerbier as this answer helped you please accept it by clicking on the checkmark below the vote balance.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the documentation, you should be able to compile and install it for BSD distributions (at least `FreeBSD`) in `/usr/local/`, just with the following:

```
make CXX=eg++ PREFIX=/usr/local/ install
```

Make sure you `gcc`'s version is equals or above 3.0.

For the record, the [installation part](https://gitlab.com/wavexx/fIcy#id11) of the documentation:

> fIcy comes with a very simple Makefile that should work on any system
>   using gcc and GNU make. Documentation is generated from these files
>   using rst2html. All standard environment flags are supported,
>   including DESTDIR/PREFIX for relocated installation. If you need to
>   use a different compiler (for example on OpenBSD), you can call make
>   as follows:
>
> ```
> make CXX=eg++ PREFIX=/usr install
> ```
>
> instead of changing manually the Makefile. Please note that, when
>   using gcc, at least g++ >= 3 is required to compile fIcy. Also note
>   that, for "fPls" to work, fIcy must be already installed (be in
>   "PATH") or a full fIcy path must be specified with -P.

Comment: Don't install anything into `/usr/` in FreeBSD you should use `/usr/local` instead (see https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hier&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html). The FreeBSD's make isn't compatible with GNU make.

Comment: Good point. Though, someone should make sure that `fIcy` official documentation takes this into account.

Answer (score 0):

@uzsolt's answer is solid.  The code compiles for me using the method described.  The `Makefile` appears to need this patch to the `install` target, however:

```
--- Makefile    2019-01-29 07:21:44.000000000 -0800
+++ Makefile    2019-07-24 11:50:40.204021000 -0700
@@ -40,7 +40,7 @@
        rm -f $(all_OBJECTS) $(all_DEPS) $(TARGETS)

 install: $(TARGETS)
-       install -p -t $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin/ $(TARGETS)
+       install -p $(TARGETS) $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin/


 # Dependencies
```

With that patch applied, you can install the compiled binaries with:

```
sudo gmake install
```

Comment: Maybe try to contact the developer of `fIcy` to fix this, and to reflect the necessary changes to the documentation as well.